# Any way to color in gray/red the text between \iffalse and \fi (like comments)?

Tags: texniccenter, comments

Is there a way to change the color of the text between `\iffalse..` and `\fi`, so to make it more (or less) visible? I mean something like the gray color which is given to comments when using `%`. 
Preferably, I am interested in making it in a different color rather than gray, for example red, since I wish to differentiate it from normal comments.

I am using TeXniccenter, so any suggestion which is valid only for this environment is also acceptable, but a general solution is better. Thanks!

Comment: I don't really see that a general solution is possible here, as you seem to be  looking for syntax highlighting in your editor, and that is mostly editor-specific I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, changing the highlighting (adding new keywords to be highlighted and the special color) is more an answer you should ask the support of TeXnicCenter.  As far as I know there is now no possibility to change this configuration by the user.

You want to mark the code between an starting line (`\iffalse` and `\fi`), the comment sign is added in each line where the color should be changed (starting with `%` until line end). You see the big difference?

But you can use a **pretty printing** of your code so that you and others can better see were an `\iffalse` starts and end:

```
\iffalse 
  code
  \iffalse
    code
    \iffalse
      code
      code
    \fi
    code
  \fi
  code
  code
\fi
```

In TeXnicCenter you can use menu point `view`->`Indentation Guide` to show indended lines in code:

[image]